# avoid for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

Im sure similar questions have been posted before but none of the answers I haven't been able to find an answer specific to my query.

I have the following code which checks each row in column 2 for the value "STRT" and if the value is not found it copies the value in Column 3 from the above row. Currently this procedure is taking more than 1hr to run as I have a dataset which has more than 300,000 rows.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(RTable)) {
    if (RTable[i,2] != "STRT") {
        RTable[i,3] <- RTable[i-1,3]
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to have a solution that looks something like this

ifelse(RTable$col2 != "STRT", RTable$col3[current row] = RTable$col3[current row -1]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: `dput(RTable)` as part of your question and post code we can run without guessing what issue is. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary variable

```
RTable$col4<-lag(RTable$col3)
```

Use the ifelse as you wanted

```
library(dplyr)
RTable %>% mutate(col3=ifelse(col2!="STRT",col3,col4))
```

Comment: Thanks Adiana - I feel your solution gets me very close to the result I need. It is still not working for some reason. Do you mind explaining what the (%>%) does?

Comment: The %>% tells to use the results of the previous expression as a first argument for the next. What kind of error are you having?

Comment: You need `library(magrittr)` to use `%>%`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(RTable)`), create the `lag` of 'col3' using `shift` ("col4"), and assign (`:=`) the values of 'col4' to 'col3' where `col2` is not equal to "STRT".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(RTable)[, col4 := shift(col3)][col2!="STRT", col3 := col4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly create a fourth column that is your third column shifted, then use your `ifelse` statement:

```
a = c(0,0,0,0)                            # just so the column indices match to yours
x = c(1,2,3,4)
y = c(2,3,4,5)
RTable = data.frame(a,x,y)

RTable[,4] = c(0,RTable[-nrow(RTable),3])  # Delete last value in column and add one to the beginning
# ifelse(RTable$col2 != "STRT", RTable$col3, RTable$col4)
```

I don't know the limitations of your data, but this is an option.